# I try to run angular 'ng serve' absolutely new project and I get a lot of errors. A project run only from C:\Windows\System32

Tags: powershell, angular-cli

I have a strange problem
I create new project in angular

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-app
cd my-app
ng serve --open
```

It's weird that when you open a project in a folder C:\Windows\System32. The project is running excellently. In another folder it makes errors. I think that problem in windows.

I use windows 10 angular 12.

when I write `ng serve --open`  that's errors I get

```
Project is attempting to disable the Ivy compiler. Angular versions 12 and higher do not support the deprecated View Engine compiler for applications. The Ivy compiler will be used to build this project.
    For additional information or if the build fails, please see https://angular.io/guide/ivy
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names         |     Size
runtime.js          | runtime       |  4.88 kB
main.js             | main          |  3.36 kB
polyfills.js        | polyfills     |  3.35 kB
styles.js           | styles        |  3.34 kB

                    | Initial Total | 14.93 kB

Build at: 2021-10-19T08:39:29.668Z - Hash: 4d3376f9322cc832a93a - Time: 5935ms

../../../c # project/AngularTemp/temp/src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Batsheva\c # project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\babel\webpack-loader.js'
Require stack:
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js        
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js  
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js        
- C:\Users\This_User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\This_User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:412:9
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:768:24)
    at NormalModule.build (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:920:15)
    at D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1322:12
    at NormalModule.needBuild (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:1192:32)

../../../c # project/AngularTemp/temp/src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed: Error: 
Cannot find module 'D:\Batsheva\c # project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\index.js'
Require stack:
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js        
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js  
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js        
- C:\Users\This_User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\This_User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:412:9
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:768:24)
    at NormalModule.build (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:920:15)
    at D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1322:12
    at NormalModule.needBuild (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:1192:32)

../../../c # project/AngularTemp/temp/src/styles.css - Error: Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Batsheva\c # project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js'
Require stack:
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js        
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js  
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js        
- C:\Users\This_User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\This_User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:412:9
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:768:24)
    at NormalModule.build (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:920:15)
    at D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1322:12

../../../c # project/AngularTemp/temp/src/app/app.component.css - Error: Module build failed (from ../../../c # project/AngularTemp/temp/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):      
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Batsheva\c # project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js'
Require stack:
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js      
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js    
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js   
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js        
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js  
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js- D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js        
- C:\Users\This_User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\This_User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at loadLoader (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
    at runLoaders (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:773:3)
    at NormalModule.build (D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:920:15)
    at D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1322:12

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0&sockPath=/sockjs-node' in 'D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp'

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0&sockPath=/sockjs-node' in 'D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp'

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0&sockPath=/sockjs-node' in 'D:\Batsheva\c# project\AngularTemp\temp'



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: Try renaming `c# project` to something without `#` and whitespace in the name